# Installation error in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb from command line in debian 9. On running installation command i am getting following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: what is the your distro

Comment: the issue is resolved